# Cannot use special principal dbo: Error 15405

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to give all the permissions to a user in the User Mapping section of a database. But, I am encountering this error:

"Cannot use special principal dbo"
[image]

Server roles of the user:

[image]

Comment: Not an actual answer to the question posted, but since you're granting db_owner to sarin, why are you even trying to assign any other roles?

Comment: This is because I am trying to install a CMs on my website and during the installation process, it says, no User or role 'sarin'. See here: http://i.imgur.com/Intaa.jpg

Comment: The user 'sarin' is already db_owner of the database, there's no need to grant any further permissions. If you're still getting this error, then you're not connecting to the database you think you are, but since you've not shown any screenshots of the actual point where you supply server/db/username, or a connection string, it's a little tricky to diagnose further.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This is happening because the user 'sarin' is the actual owner of the database "dbemployee" - as such, they can *only* have db_owner, and cannot be assigned any further database roles.

Nor do they need to be. If they're the DB owner, they already have permission to do anything they want to within this database.

(To see the owner of the database, open the properties of the database. The Owner is listed on the general tab).

To change the owner of the database, you can use [sp_changedbowner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630.aspx) or [ALTER AUTHORIZATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx) (the latter being apparently the preferred way for future development, but since this kind of thing tends to be a one off...)

Comment: It may be worth noting that this can help resolve configuration mistakes or errors. After SP2 was installed for SQL Server 2012, my local SSMS was hosed. I had to uninstall/reinstall SSMS entirely and I know others have as well; many MS blogs have identified the issues all the way back to June 2014. Using the ALTER AUTHORIZATION mentioned as well as relocating all ldf and mdf files resolved all issues.

Comment: Hi there, I have a further question here. I'm receiving the error above in slightly different circumstances. There's a DB on which dbo User name appears with my Login name (Orbus\Gksiazek)

Answer (score 38):

> Fix: Cannot use the special principal ‘sa’. Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15405

When importing a database in your SQL instance you would find yourself with Cannot use the special principal 'sa'. Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15405 popping out when setting the sa user as the DBO of the database. To fix this,
Open SQL Management Studio and Click New Query. Type:

```
USE mydatabase
exec sp_changedbowner 'sa', 'true'
```

Close the new query and after viewing the security of the sa, you will find that that sa is the DBO of the database. (14444)

Source:
http://www.noelpulis.com/fix-cannot-use-the-special-principal-sa-microsoft-sql-server-error-15405/

Comment: This is the case also if the DB has no valid owner anymore.  (User deleted, server restored to another box etc)

Comment: Note that the second (`map`) argument of the `sp_changedbowner` has been deprecated and no longer has any effect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changedbowner-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't help for SQL databases where SharePoint is connected. db_securityadmin is required for the configuration databases. In order to add db_securityadmin, you will need to change the owner of the database to an administrative account. You can use that account just for dbo roles.